# How do I make hyperlinks a different colour in the Wordpress Amadeus theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink, wordpress-theming

Using Wordpress Amadeus theme (free version) I've tried to make the hyperlinks visible. There is no option to change the hyperlink colour in the 'Colours' section in the Wordpress customizer.

I modified the CSS code to a different colour, but the changes weren't made active.

I then added code to the style.css file for the theme, (following instructions from a YouTube video) and uploaded the modified file back to the website.

The code I added was:

```
    /* unvisited link */
a:link {
color: blue;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
color: orange;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
color: red;
}
```

After right clicking on the link on the page, and selecting 'Inspect element', I found that the CSS code for the a:link tag was crossed out, making it inactive.

[CSS code for hyperlink colour change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCPy8.jpg)

I also tried adding the code to the 'Additional CSS' section in the Wordpress Customizer, and the changes still aren't applying.

How can I make a hyperlink a different colour in this Wordpress Amadeus theme?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you may have encountered [CSS specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). Basically, the more specific a CSS rule the higher priority it takes over other, less specific rules. For example:

```
a { ... }
a.primary { ... } // This rule takes precedence!
```

If you have an `a` tag with the class `primary`, the second rule will apply (regardless of where it is in the file)

You could edit your theme to change the offending rules.

Another, less preferable option, would be to add `!important` before the semicolon. This will most likely come back to haunt you in versions to come, so you should avoid this.

If you would like to learn more about managing your CSS, try reading about [ITCSS](https://www.xfive.co/blog/itcss-scalable-maintainable-css-architecture/) and [BEM](http://getbem.com/).